# How to get max number from Array<String> in TS orJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, frontend

I'd like to create like this function in JS or TS but I couldn't.
Please teach me ...!
It is better if its function is made by functional-programming.

・Input type:Array(String) 
・Output type:string or undefined

ex

| Input | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `["","0","3"]` | `"3"` |
| `["","",""]` | `undefined` |
| `["0","0","0"]` | `"0"` |
| `["1","3","2"]` | `"3"` |

Comment: Hi @Gab53, welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question it is expected for you to show your code and attempt. You can [edit] your question to include your try to show us where you're getting stuck

Comment: have you heard of `Math.max`

Answer (score 0):

- Filter out all non-number elements from array.
- Convert all string-number to Number type.
- Use `Math.max` to get the largest value from array.

```js
function getMaxValue(input) {
  if (input.length) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, input);
  }
}

function sanitize(input) {
  return input.filter(i => {
    if (i === "" || i === null) {
      return false;
    }
    return !isNaN(i);
  }).map(i => Number(i));
}

let input1 = ["", "", "0"];
let input2 = [1, 3, 5];
let input3 = ["1", "", "5"];
let input4 = ["", "", ""];
let input5 = [undefined, null, "", "", "", "10"];

console.log(getMaxValue(sanitize(input1)));
console.log(getMaxValue(sanitize(input2)));
console.log(getMaxValue(sanitize(input3)));
console.log(getMaxValue(sanitize(input4)));
console.log(getMaxValue(sanitize(input5)));
```

Comment: Note that this will break if `input` has a large amount of numbers in it (In my browser, it breaks when the input array has more than `125257` numbers in it), due to the max amount of arguments you can pass to `Math.max()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
    const findMaximuminArray = (arr) => {
  let max = arr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > max) {
      max = arr[i];
    }
  }
  if(max === "") return undefined;
  return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using strings in your example, such as `"1"`, but all of them contain digits actually, so I'm not sure what you're really trying to do.

However, here's a function that generates the results you want using [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide):

```js
_.compose(x => x ? x : undefined, _.max)
```

Whatever array argument you pass to it, it will get the maximum value and then convert it to `undefined` if it is falsy, as is the case for the empty string.

Here's the results generated for your input:

```js
const fun = _.compose(x => x ? x : undefined, _.max);
const input = [["","0","3"],["","",""],["0","0","0"],["1","3","2"]]
_.forEach(x => console.log(fun(x)), input);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
```